# Check if my App is running in Android

Tags: android

I have an application which involves sound pool - On start of the application all the sounds are loaded after which main screen is loaded.

Now, I would like to check if the application is running - if is not running I would like to reload the application - if it is running I don't want reload the application.

For which I tried the following:

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
 for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
   if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.me.checkprocess"))
   {
    Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
   }
   else
   {
     Log.e("Result", "App is not running - Needs to reload);
  }
}
```

This gives the results out perfectly but keeps on checking until procInfos.size is lesser that 0. Until the app gets process com.me.checkprocess true - it is always false? so it always gets into the else part first.

So for example: If the total process is 30. And my process com.me.checkprocess is running @29th. When execute the condition. Until 28th process it is else and @29th process it gets into the condition true.

How to fix this part - I would like to get to else part only after total process is checked?

Let me know!

Comment: Use `break;` statement.

Comment: `Missing quote` at end of this line `Log.e("Result", "App is not running - Needs to reload);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can just add

```
break;
```

below

```
Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
```

in `if` statement

Answer (score 3):

Just put an break inside the for-loop.

```
 for(...){
    if(){
       break;
    } 
 }
```

This is definitely not clean, but does the thing you want.

**EDIT 2

I think it would be easier if you just extract this task in a method.

```
public boolean isProcessRunning(String process) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(process)) {
            return true;
        }  
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (isProcessRunning("my_process")) {
        // Do what you need
    } else {
        // restart your app
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what is the cleaner way?

Comment: @HarryJoy "clean" is subjective. I would prefer the break over a complicated termination condition or a construction with a boolean variable.

Comment: @Henry yeah I got your point, but actually I was honestly asking if *c4pone* also has some more cleaner way to do this then break.

Comment: yes, I saw that. Thanks for sharing it. It's always good to provide a better way to do the thing in answer. And the name is Harry Joy ;P

Comment: Thanks C4pone.. But how to fix the else part here? If app is running I don't need to load. If not I need to reload. Your code works sometimes and not everytime.

Comment: Hi all, check out my answer for another alternative to both `break` and reworking it into a `while` statment

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should be doing.

```
   if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.me.checkprocess"))
   {
    Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
    break;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The other listed answers will work, but I agree with c4pone - in a loop such as this, break seems like a bad way to do it - especially as using a `break` means that if you add another condition around your if statement, there's a chance that the `break` may no longer function in exiting the `for` loop - in some ways it's analogous to a `goto` statement in other languages

Another alternative to your problem is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
   if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.me.checkprocess"))
   {
        Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
        i = procInfos.size();
   }
   else
   {
        Log.e("Result", "App is not running - Needs to reload);
   }
}
```

Which will also break the loop, as it sets your counter variable to the termination clause, meaning once it's found, the loop will exit.

**EDIT:**

After the OP's comment below, I have a feeling that the solution he wants is this:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
   if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.me.checkprocess"))
   {
       found = true;
   }
}

if(found)
{
    Log.e("Result", "App is running - Doesn't need to reload");
    i = procInfos.size();
}
else
{
    Log.e("Result", "App is not running - Needs to reload);
}
```

Which is nothing to do with exiting the loop prematurely, as all of us thought from reading the question, but is instead to only output the result once

Comment: Again. This goes directly to else part first and then goes to if part. So for example if the total process is 30.. and "com.me.checkprocess" is running on 29th - till 28th the app will go to else part ("needs to reload") and then @29th it will say true doesn't need to reload.

Comment: Of course it will. At this point I'm suspecting that you've not worded your original question well at all. Do you want the else clause to only execute once? If so, I've edited my answer to give you a solution

Comment: Yep. The condition is like that. Sorry for wrong communication. I have also edited the question properly. 

else part should occur only when the process is not there. Not everytime it goes in the process. 

My code or your code always goes to else part then goes to if part.

Comment: Else part and if part working fine but...the code works very intermediately. Sometimes it is true / sometimes is false. Hope the code that I had tried as above in my question is the correct way to get the process name right?

Comment: TBH, it seems to me that your check is a bit pointless - if the app is getting to this point in code, it **must** be running. I don't know anything about your app, but it seems to me you really want to be checking that your sound files exist, which is an entirely different check

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean isAppRunning(Context context) {
```

// check with the first task(task in the foreground)
 // in the returned list of tasks

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
 context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> services =
activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
 if
 (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName().toString()))
 {
 return true;
 }
 return false;
 }
```