# Android when i close my app then How i can restart my app after x time duration?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I am working on Android app which have worked on TV devices,i want when i close my app,and if no one touch the mouse or keyboard,then my app is start automatically after x time duration,this is possible?if yes then please help,Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, in a Android Service you check if your app is running (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085897/check-if-my-app-is-running-in-android)) if not, you can launch your app. For check user interaction check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible 
U can take help from service just start one timerthread on Ondestroy() of your app means On last activity or u can perform this action on close of your app.
Check with ideal state from thread if any broadcast from mouse or keyboard u will get then reset your timer thread according to it.
When ever your timer thread reach at your time just start activity programmatic  like

```
 Intent i = Context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(Context.getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: can u please explain your ans?

Comment: hii Frahan where u dont understand dude

Comment: bro how and were i can start timer thread?and if user is intercating with the phone then how i can reset my timer and start again my timer?if user not interacting with the phone then start my application after x time duration..

Comment: bro u can get all screen touch event on Google correct then just reset ur timer on that particular touch event other wise timer is running normal and start your in your service like when user mobile ideal then only like in touch event if not call in last 1 mint or whatever u want to set then just start your service for X time and whenever it will complete X time then broadcast start your activity with my above code :)

Comment: bro can u please give me a step wise example?it would be very kind of u.

Comment: friend its not possible 4 me coz i m very busy wd my work so sorry dude i can only give hint or idea which i already gave u :) just try dude it will not that hard that u think just try once

Comment: basically now the logic is change..now i start my app after every 3minutes if user user interacting with the app or not..

Comment: now i want to do when my app iss killed then after 3minutes my app is start auto.

Comment: this is possible when app is killed then it is auto start?

Comment: how u get ur app killed by other

Comment: can u also get event when i kill ur app from native setting

Comment: i have a buttonclick listner when i click see the code:                    btn_closeicon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_closeicon);

  btn_closeicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
       System.exit(0);

   }
  });

Comment: ohk best of luck dude :) i think self logic is batter then others really :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48932/discussion-between-bhanu-sharma-and-farhan-shah)

Answer (score 0):

Its Possible by using PendingIntent in your service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html